# Formula for the forward rates?

Tags: interest-rates, forward-rate

I'm reading a book about interest rate modelling. It states the following formula

P(0,T) = exp(-sum of the forward rates)

But I thought it's the average of the forward rates?

[image]

Comment: Um, rotate picture first please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The price of the zero-coupon bond is the discount factor for this maturity.
In the world of exponential compounding formulas are of the form $\exp(\sum \cdots)$.
With a replication argument if we want to invest money for $n$ years what can we do.
We invest for one year $r_0 = F(0,1)$ then after this year we invest for another year, the rate for this today is $F(1,2)$, after another year we invest again for one year, the rate for this today is $F(2,3)$.
After all the discount factor is simply
$$
\exp(\sum_{i=1}^n F(0,n-1,n)),
$$
where the $0$ indicates that the forward rates are traded/observed at time $0$ and $n-1$,$n$ means that it is the forward rate for the respective year. So it is the sum, not the average.